# Specify a core to run a python script on. systemd

Tags: python, debian, python-3.5, systemd

I have this systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Toasty
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/mnt/data/Toasty
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/python3.5 /mnt/data/Toasty/run.py
Type=idle
Restart=always
RestartSec=2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What i want is the ability to specify a core for my python code to run on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `ExecStartPost=/path/to/taskset -cp 1 $MAINPID` to your `Install` section.

```
[Unit]
Description=Toasty
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/mnt/data/Toasty
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/python3.5 /mnt/data/Toasty/run.py
ExecStartPost=/path/to/taskset -cp 1 $MAINPID
Type=idle
Restart=always
RestartSec=2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 4):

What about systemd [CPUAffinity](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd-system.conf.5.html):

> CPUAffinity=
>
> Configures the CPU affinity for the service manager as well
> as the default CPU affinity for all forked off processes.
> Takes a list of CPU indices or ranges separated by either
> whitespace or commas. CPU ranges are specified by the lower
> and upper CPU indices separated by a dash. This option may be
> specified more than once, in which case the specified CPU
> affinity masks are merged. If the empty string is assigned,
> the mask is reset, all assignments prior to this will have no
> effect. Individual services may override the CPU affinity for
> their processes with the CPUAffinity= setting in unit files,
> see systemd.exec(5).

Processes under the following service will use logical CPU cores 0 to 20 and 288 to 308:

```
[Unit]
Description=Toasty
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/mnt/data/Toasty
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/python3.5 /mnt/data/Toasty/run.py
CPUAffinity=0-20,288-308
Type=idle
Restart=always
RestartSec=2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I guess this option is for the systemd process,  not the specified service

Comment: If I understand your comment, this option (`CPUAffinity`) applies the constraint on `/usr/local/bin/python3.5` and all the other processes under this service. I have extensively tested this method and it works. All the processes under this service will be constrained by the defined `CPUAffinity`.

Comment: You are right! It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

(TL;DR at the end)

You can achieve this with the `taskset` command, which is part of the `util-linux` package.
Most distros already come with it, if it's not available on your system install it with:

```
apt-get install util-linux
```

---

Use the following to view a process' CPU affinity in hexadecimal:

```
taskset -p [pid]
```

which will return something along `ff`, equal to `11111111` in binary or `all cores`.

Specify the 'c' option (e.g.: `taskset -cp [pid]`) to get a human readable format like `0-7`.

To pin a already running process to specific cores use either

```
taskset -p [hexmask] [pid]

ex: taskset -p 0x1 4242
```

or

```
taskset -cp [list] [pid]

ex: taskset -cp 0 4242
```

with the 'c' option, you can use a comma separated list or ranges for cores (e.g.: 0,2,5-7).

---

**TL;DR:**

Now that we have the basics, lets get to your use case. It's possible to start a process pinned to cores with `taskset` like so:

```
taskset 0x1 vlc
```

Which will start and pin vlc to core 0.

In case that you want to dedicate a whole core only to that one (or multiple) process(es) you should take a look at the `isolcpus` kernel parameter and integrate that into your grub configuration. It will reserve those cores then during boot from being used by other processes, except those you assign with `taskset`.

Comment: Yeah ive seen taskset, but i cant implement it into systemd as far as i can tell. I need the process to auto restart upon dying. Hence i need something that keeps it running, but i also need something to force it to run on a specific core